# If the parts inside a friction shifter are rusty, should I replace them?

Tags: shifter, shifting

I recently got a bike from my neighbor, and it has shifting problems. It won't shift out of the lowest gear on the rear cassette. The shifters don't do anything. I can pull the cable by hand, and it'll shift gears, but then it'll just go back to the smallest gear. I checked inside the shifters, and it looks slightly rusty, which makes sense because it was left outside. Should I get those shifters replaced?

Comment: You just need to tighten the screw on top a little bit. That adds more friction; the symptom you described is typical of too little friction. I recommend putting threadlocker on that bolt before making the adjustment.

Comment: If the cables move smoothly it's unlikely that rust is a problem.

Comment: If the shifter lever is not moving freely, then rust inside the shifters could be a cause.  Strip and clean them before replacing.

Comment: "slightly rusty" is incredibly subjective. I have seen stuff that has been structurally unsound described as "Slightly rusty" and I have seen stuff that has got a slight tinge of orange described that way.  If possible, please post photos so we know how bad it is.